# keep image link stable on webpage.

Tags: hyperlink

Full disclosure, I've never made a website before, I'm learning as I go.

I searched the site for answers on this but I don't even know that the terms that I should be using/looking for are.

I'm trying to make a homepage with a background image layer and on top are horizontally patterned circles (think polka dots) that have links to other pages. I got the circles down and the hover effects on them. I don't understand how to make them stick to the position they are in so that different browser sizes or resolutions don't hide some of them. I can do that on the background image with the backstretch script but how do I apply it to the dots? I downloaded the Modernizr script but I'm not even sure that it's the right thing.

Basically I'm trying to have the page act like these: https://thankfulregistry.com/ or http://assemblylondon.com/ when it is resized.

If you sort of know what I'm trying to do, I'd appreciate the help. Even if you just tell me what I should me looking for to research the thing on my own (correct terminology).

Thanks!

-Sophie.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you'd like to position them you should be using CSS (cascading style sheet). This site will help you out a TON!
http://w3schools.com/css/default.asp

For the circles becoming links, you could either use an image map or you could just make the image of the circle a link

```
<a href="WHERE YOU WANT TO LINK TO"><img src="URL/LOCATION OF THE PICTURE" height="NUMBER IN PIXELS OR PERCENT" width="NUMBER IN PIXELS OR PERCENT"/></a>
```

If you need more help let me know!

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, my css sheet looks like this: but with like 35 points/letters for the dots:                                  #c {
 position: absolute;
 border-radius: 100px;
 background-color: #000000;
 width: 70px;
 height: 70px;
 top: 133px;
 left: 123px;
}
#c:hover{ background-image:url(HoverImages/test1.png)}                        I imaging the positioning is what's wrong. I'll take another look

Comment: Sorry I just re-read your post. Instead of setting the position of the dots by pixels, try doing it by percent. eg (css) top:10%; right:10% this would make it 10% of the page down from the top and 10% of the page from the right just set it like this for the rest of the dots. Hope I helped!

Comment: omg! this was it, thanks so much! the dots are moving along with the resizing of the window!